# How to delete previous builds on AppHarbor?

Tags: build, appharbor

I have several builds that are on AppHarbor that, while they build, they are not working correctly. I would like to delete them and only have "good" builds in the list. How do I delete builds?

All I see are "deploy" buttons.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to purge builds from AppHarbor. What's your use-case?